# How to make Transmission torrent client auto start and seed upon PC startup?

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, windows, transmission

## Transmission seeder

### Objective

The Transmission tool provided with my Linux doesn’t seeds the torrent automatically like bit Torrent does on Windows. I want it to start with my PC and start seeding without me having to launch the application and manually hit the start button on each torrent for it to seed. I need to set it up to work that way on Linux.

### Motivation

Return the favor to the torrent community.

### Ethics

Giving back, selflessness

### Initial Hypothesis

I looked about it a while ago and I think I might need to download a Transmission Daemon and let it auto-start with my computer.

### Updates

***21/08/18***

**17:04:48**    I need to get the daemon tool and the CLI to configure. It isn’t simply about setting it up. There are lots of things that can be done. I can control the torrent client from my phone. I can white or black list IP addresses. Its gonna be fun.

**17:13:38**    The daemon and CLI is already installed. I only need to configure it.

**17:31:59** I am done configuring. The configuration was already done by me on the GUI application. That was all. All that I changed in it was adding my WiFi as an allowed client. I have added transmission-daemon to startup application. Let’s see how it work. Or if it does or not. I am currently upgrading my system so I cannot restart my system right now.

**23:45:24**    I did restarted the system but I couldn’t make the daemon start by adding the `transmission-daemon` command in the startup applications list. I need to duck duck go it.

***22/08/18***

**19:26:56** I posted [a question on Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463939/how-to-make-transmission-torrent-client-auto-start-and-seed-upon-pc-startup/463961#463961). A guy answered that I might use qbittorrent instead. I download it just now. Lets see if that works.

**19:37:46** It does starts mimimized and starts seeding on its own. I only need to make sure it does the same when the system starts. It also seems to have features like managing seperately the torrent files for completed and incomplete state and automatically adding from the chosen folder.

**19:41:43** I confirmed the correct steps for [adding apps to startup from the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html). I’m going to try it out right now.

**19:49:04** It did work. qbittorrent started automatically and started seeding. Even though the objective says “I need to set it up to work that way on linux.”, where “it” was transmission but the ignoring the words and looking at the real motive, my seeding is working on it own.

**19:55:29** I configured it to start minimized and to show the icon which was only for test. Next I am going to turn the icon off. That will be the final icing.

### Conclusion

I wasn’t able to configure transmission to work my way and the credit goes to my lack of Linux experience, still my job is done. qbittorrent works. I downloaded it. Gave it the torrent files and the download folder. It mapped, checked and started seeding the torrent pretty easily. Then I added qbittorrent in the startup application’s list. That did the magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `startup applications` (default program installed in linux) you can set transmission to start when you start the pc.
 

You can do the same with qBittorent which you won' t regret to try, it will start automatically to seed the torrents and it has many features.
Quick instructions for ubuntu:

To use these PPAs please use the following command and make sure your version is supported:

## qBittorrent Stable

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
```

## or qBittorrent Unstable

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-unstable
```

## Then install qBittorrent by doing this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

When using `startup applications` in the Command field write:
qBittorent

Answer (score 1):

Put the daemon in crontab:

```
(crontab -l;echo "@reboot transmission-daemon") | crontab
```

Comment: Doesnt it fail in case of cold boot?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might better:

```
 service enable transmission-daemon
```

This will make systemd create a init service for you.

Addendum, okay so ubuntu has some fixing that must be done:
Create this file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d/override.conf
```

with this content:

```
[Service]
User=
Type=
Type=simple
User=debian-transmission
Group=debian-transmission
```

then you must execute this in order to reload systemd config:

```
$systemctl daemon-reload
```

and finally you must execute:

```
$systemctl start transmission-daemon.service
```

And then finally 
     service enable transmission-daemon

[Source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2386355&page=2&p=13745816#post13745816)

Comment: user@machine:~$  service transmission-daemon enable
         * Usage: /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|status}'

Comment: This was returned

Answer (score 1):

On debian, transmission-daemon is nearly what you need. But, it does not seed at startup... (what a pity).

To solve that, you can make another service to resume all torrents in your list:

You put this somewhere, like: /etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon-start.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Publish the mpd port to the internet
PartOf=transmission-daemon.service
After=transmission-daemon.service

[Service] 
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-remote --torrent all --start
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

You still need authentification, so put in your folder a file named .netrc with

```
# Transmission daemon
machine localhost
login USERNAME
password PASSWORD
```

And enable the service

```
systemctl enable transmission-daemon-start
systemctl start transmission-daemon-start
```

The script will start all torrent, not only the paused. This need a bit of rework :-)